# Fabricjs detect mouse over object path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to capture `object:over` in Fabric.js only if mouse is on the shape itself and not on the imaginary square that contains it?

I have a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XS8J9/1/), which contains an U shape. You can see that even if i have the pointer inside the U and not touching any of the lines, it still detects it as a `object:over` event.

[image]

**Javascript:**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c1", {
    isDrawingMode: false
});

canvas.loadFromJSON(objectsJson, function () {
    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on("object:over", function () {
    console.log("object over");
});
canvas.on("object:out", function () {
    console.log("object out");
});

// code to capture mouse over object while isDrawingMode = false
canvas.findTarget = (function (originalFn) {
    return function () {
        var target = originalFn.apply(this, arguments);
        if (target) {
            if (this._hoveredTarget !== target) {
                canvas.fire('object:over', { target: target });
                if (this._hoveredTarget) {
                    canvas.fire('object:out', { target: this._hoveredTarget });
                }
                this._hoveredTarget = target;
            }
        }
        else if (this._hoveredTarget) {
            canvas.fire('object:out', { target: this._hoveredTarget });
            this._hoveredTarget = null;
        }
        return target;
    };
})(canvas.findTarget);
```

Comment: You need `perPixelTargetFind` and `targetFindTolerance` (see this demo — http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/)

Comment: @kangax: Works perfect! although i think `targetFindTolerance` works only "inside" the element, not also outside .i've set it to a 100 to but still activates only when i "touch" the object. BTW, good gratulations for this awesome project you have made. It just works out-of-box! Awesome

Comment: perfect! glad you like it

Answer (score 2):

In `fabric.js,` for each shape there would created virtual box and when you intersect with this virtual box, the binded event is triggered.

During the create of any shape on `fabric.js,` this below function create the virtual box by creating various points eg:
**top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, middle left, middle right, middle bottom and middle top.**

```
setCoords: function() {
   var strokeWidth = this.strokeWidth > 1 ? this.strokeWidth : 0,
   padding = this.padding,
   theta = degreesToRadians(this.angle);

   this.currentWidth = (this.width + strokeWidth) * this.scaleX + padding * 2;
   this.currentHeight = (this.height + strokeWidth) * this.scaleY + padding * 2;

   // If width is negative, make postive. Fixes path selection issue
   if (this.currentWidth < 0) {
    this.currentWidth = Math.abs(this.currentWidth);
   }

   var _hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(this.currentWidth / 2, 2) +
    Math.pow(this.currentHeight / 2, 2));

   var _angle = Math.atan(isFinite(this.currentHeight / this.currentWidth) ? this.currentHeight / this.currentWidth : 0);

   // offset added for rotate and scale actions
   var offsetX = Math.cos(_angle + theta) * _hypotenuse,
      offsetY = Math.sin(_angle + theta) * _hypotenuse,
      sinTh = Math.sin(theta),
      cosTh = Math.cos(theta);

   var coords = this.getCenterPoint();
   var tl = {
    x: coords.x - offsetX,
    y: coords.y - offsetY
   };
   var tr = {
    x: tl.x + (this.currentWidth * cosTh),
    y: tl.y + (this.currentWidth * sinTh)
   };
   var br = {
    x: tr.x - (this.currentHeight * sinTh),
    y: tr.y + (this.currentHeight * cosTh)
   };
   var bl = {
    x: tl.x - (this.currentHeight * sinTh),
    y: tl.y + (this.currentHeight * cosTh)
   };
   var ml = {
    x: tl.x - (this.currentHeight/2 * sinTh),
    y: tl.y + (this.currentHeight/2 * cosTh)
   };
   var mt = {
    x: tl.x + (this.currentWidth/2 * cosTh),
    y: tl.y + (this.currentWidth/2 * sinTh)
   };
   var mr = {
    x: tr.x - (this.currentHeight/2 * sinTh),
    y: tr.y + (this.currentHeight/2 * cosTh)
   };
   var mb = {
    x: bl.x + (this.currentWidth/2 * cosTh),
    y: bl.y + (this.currentWidth/2 * sinTh)
   };
   var mtr = {
    x: mt.x,
    y: mt.y
   };
  this.oCoords = {
    // corners
    tl: tl, tr: tr, br: br, bl: bl,
    // middle
    ml: ml, mt: mt, mr: mr, mb: mb,
    // rotating point
    mtr: mtr
   };

   // set coordinates of the draggable boxes in the corners used to scale/rotate the image
   this._setCornerCoords && this._setCornerCoords();

   return this;
}
```

So whenever you intersect with any of these 8 points by mouse, the attached event would be fired.

As I know `fabric.js`, it does not provide the functionality you wanted.

**UPDATE:-**

As RaraituL said, the pixel detection is possible through  `perPixelTargetFind()`, you can get the example on here. http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/

Comment: Seems that `perPixelTargetFind` changes this behavior

Comment: Looks intresting, have you tried it with `perPixelTargetFind`?

Comment: Yes, it works! check [http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/](http://fabricjs.com/per-pixel-drag-drop/)